# Psychonauts, what to do with 'psychonauts-linux-06042012-bin'?

Tags: executable

Psychonauts came in a neat file called `psychonauts-linux-06042012-bin`.

The file system calls it an executable, but I can't find a way to execute it.

Ubuntu suggested using "PyPar2" to open it like an archive, which made it into a bunch of .par2 files, but it then couldn't find anything else to open those.

It seems that other people have been able to start the game, so what should I do differently?

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal and change to the directory where you downloaded the file, most cases will be `~/Downloads`:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

make the file executable

```
chmod +x psychonauts-linux-06042012-bin
```

run the installation / executable file

```
./psychonauts-linux-06042012-bin
```

---

Has an option you can also open your Home Folder and navigate to Downloads, once there right click on the downloaded file and select properties

[image]

on the permissions tab make sure that the *Execute* option is set, if not do so and close.

[image]

Now you can double click you file. The installer will pop-up

[image]

You can then install the game to the destination you chose and that should be all.

Comment: Screenshots and everything, wow! I suppose a simple question now would be whether or not it's made for 64 bit, as that's what I use. Double clicking after allowing execution doesn't seem to do anything, and trying it from Terminal returns `bash: ./psychonauts-linux-06042012-bin: No such file or directory` A quick LS shows that it certainly is. Thanks for your great help, by the way!

Comment: I installed it and its running on Ubuntu 12.04 x64, it requires only a few extra packages because of the sound ([check here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148514/sdl-openaudio-failed-no-available-audio-device-while-starting-psychonauts), I posted a Q&A). The file should be where you downloaded it, after making it exec install it and it will be installed in your home. Don't know what is happening but should be simple to solve. If you are around ping me (@brunopereira) and I will invt you for chatting so we can solve this.

Comment: Would that be in the chat on Askubuntu? I don't have the reputation to use it yet, sorry to say. I tried using `bash` to run it instead and it said "cannot execute binary file." I tried re-downloading, too. Do you think it could be a problem with Ubuntu?

Comment: Fixed it! Using `file psychonauts-linux-06042012-bin` revealed that it is 32 bit. I ran `apt-get install ia32-libs` and executed it from Unity and the installer is currently running. Thanks for your detailed help!

Comment: Great success ;) Have fun playing it.

Answer (score 1):

Easy - if you know how: Just handle it as a zip-archive.

```
unzip psychonauts-linux-06042012-bin -d [where you want it to be extracted to]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just running the binary file on the command line, e.g.

```
bash psychonauts-linux-06042012-bin
```

Seems that the said archive might be a self-extracting archive.