# 'SDL_OpenAudio failed: No available audio device' while starting Psychonauts

Tags: 64-bit, package-management, games

Psychonauts fails to start on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with the error

> SDL_OpenAudio failed: No available audio device

What do I need to do to start the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Psychonauts port to Linux is only released in 32bit and requires that some sound libraries are installed.

Open a terminal, or if you wish look for the package in the Ubuntu Software Center, and install `libpulse0:i386`

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386
```

After you have done so the game will start normally and the sound will be working.

[image]