# "libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: apt, software-installation

I wrastled with the program according to the info in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148426/psychonauts-what-to-do-with-psychonauts-linux-06042012-bin/). Now it is installed but I can't figure out how to run it. A friend running the same version of Ubuntu had no problems getting it to start after installing it the same way.

This is what I've done:

```
$ ./Psychonauts
./Psychonauts: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I went ahead and:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++.so.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libstdc++.so.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libstdc++.so.6'
```

It should be noted that I only started using Linux a few days ago.

Okay, so I did manage to install apt-file and apt-file update.

However then we hit another snag.

```
usagiyojimbo@Usagi:~$ sudo apt-file find libstdc++.so.6
[sudo] password for usagiyojimbo: 
E: The cache is empty. You need to run 'apt-file update' first.
```

I have done that, when I do it says:

```
File is up-to-date.
Ignoring source without Contents File:
a link they won't let me post
```

Or

```
File is up-to-date.
Downloading Index a link
No Index available.
Downloading complete file a link
```

I am still getting the same error when I try to run Psychonauts.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6`

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" for all packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-for-all-packages)

Answer (score 23):

You get the error message:

> ```
> E: Unable to locate package libstdc++.so.6
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libstdc++.so.6'
> ```

because you tried to install a file `libstdc++.so.6` that you can't install, because it is located in a debian package.

You can use `apt-file` to search for the package that contains that file. To install it, type:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Then you have to update the index.

```
sudo apt-file update
```

After that, you can search for the package which contains the file `libstdc++.so.6`:

```
sudo apt-file find libstdc++.so.6
```

Then you find a lot packages that contains the searched file. In your case, the correct package is `libstdc++6`:

```
libstdc++6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Then you can install the needed package:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Comment: Okay, so I did manage to install apt-file and apt-file update.

However then we hit another snag.

usagiyojimbo@Usagi:~$ sudo apt-file find libstdc++.so.6
[sudo] password for usagiyojimbo: 
E: The cache is empty. You need to run 'apt-file update' first.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-file update` and after that `sudo apt-file find libstdc++.so.6`. Read above answer exactly.

Comment: Not sure what I did differently, but it apt-file find worked this time. I get the list of packages. When I try to install it says libstdc++6 is already the newest version. 

When I try to ./Psychonauts it still says no such file or directory.

Comment: And if you're messing around with 32-bit hardware, make sure to specify at the end: sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386

Answer (score 12):

I think Psychonauts is a 32bit application. You will need to install:

```
apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Comment: That's correct for me

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, just used a few more characters than you needed:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

... should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it with the help of a friend of mine.

Since the binary was of 32-bit, we could fix it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll share with you the way that worked for me.
First of all you should find if any other copy of this file is already on your machine:

```
$ locate libstdc++.so.6
```

the output:

```
/snap/core/6405/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/core/6405/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
/snap/core/6405/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py
/snap/core/6531/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/core/6531/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
/snap/core/6531/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py
/snap/core/6673/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/core/6673/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
/snap/core/6673/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
```

As you can see there are many `/snap/core/...` versions of this file. (if not this method doesn't works for you)

The you should make a backup from the existing file:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.backup
```

Then you can replace the latest snap version into the corrupted file:

```
sudo cp /snap/core/6673/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

The try running desired command again
.