# Error while loading shared libraries, but I've installed the libraries

Tags: 13.10, executable, shared-library

I've been trying to get Psychonauts to run on my computer for over a month now. I previously posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409821/install-package-for-missing-libraries/409831?noredirect=1#comment537405_409831), but even after following those directions I am still stuck. I have successfully installed the missing package that Psychonauts cites when as the reason for not running:

```
usagiyojimbo@Usagi:~/psychonauts$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However, when I try to run the program it still responds exactly the same way. Here is the ls:

```
usagiyojimbo@Usagi:~/psychonauts$ ls
DisplaySettings.ini  libSDL-1.2.so.0             psychonauts.png
Documents            Psychonauts                 README-linux.txt
icon.bmp             PsychonautsData2.pkg        uninstall-psychonauts.sh
libopenal.so.1       Psychonauts Manual Win.pdf  WorkResource
```

I have been doing this:

```
usagiyojimbo@Usagi:~/psychonauts$ ./Psychonauts
./Psychonauts: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think Psychonauts is a 32bit application. You will need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to run

$ strace ./psychonauts

and watch out for open() calls for libstdc++. And then you work from that.