# How to fix missing libwayland-egl.so.1 and libuser-accounts.so in ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, system-settings

I tried to use the command `gnome-control center -l` and it gave me an errors saying some shared objects are missing . This is the result :

`gnome-control-center -l`

```
libwayland-egl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so
Unknown option -l
```

Run `/usr/bin/unity-control-center --help` to see a full list of available command line options.

So I tried this and it also gave the same result :

`unity-control-center -l`

```
libwayland-egl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so
Unknown option -l
```

Run `unity-control-center --help` to see a full list of available command line options.

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409821/install-package-for-missing-libraries) thread I tried the following commands and those gave me the following results :

`sudo apt-file update`

`sudo apt-file find libwayland-egl.so.1`

```
libhybris: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libhybris-egl/libwayland-egl.so.1
libhybris: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libhybris-egl/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
libwayland-egl1-mesa: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
libwayland-egl1-mesa: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
libwayland-egl1-mesa-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-utopic: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-utopic: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
```

It said about missing dependency account plugin ubuntuone . So I tried installing it but it installed some packages meant for ubuntu mobile . I removed those wrong packages and reinstalled the previous ones following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50622/how-to-reinstall-many-removed-packages-at-once) thread and after that everything is good like before but the error I mentioned before about `libwayland-egl.so` didn't get solved . And still `user-accounts.so` shows failed to load .

How do I solve this ? I am trying to solve it because I can't access user-accounts from system settings . Whenever I try to access user accounts it always keep showing system settings over and over again . I can't even close it in anyway possible . It just keeps showing up .

Answer (score 6):

I had a same problem with `Cinnamon 2.8.6` on `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS` I managed to fix it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-trusty
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu official wiki page gives all the solution required :

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

P.S : If you face above issues like me , thats probably because you don't have the recommended .so file installed properly . Always check if you have anything missing as mentioned in the stack .