# Ubuntu stalls when accessing "System Settings" -> "User Accounts"

Tags: 14.04

I currently have Ubuntu 14.04 but whenever I try to access "System Settings" -> "User Accounts" the OS just stalls there. I can still access other things. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Start it from command line and see if it errors out. (`unity-control-center`)

Comment: I do get errors:

libwayland-egl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix:

[How to fix missing libwayland-egl.so.1 and libuser-accounts.so in ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672620/how-to-fix-missing-libwayland-egl-so-1-and-libuser-accounts-so-in-ubuntu-14-04-3)

sudo apt-get install libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-trusty

I didn't realize it was stuck on a loop. Duplicate post.